# Trying to create a trigger in mariadb that looks up a separate value from another table and passes it to another function

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

Using MariaDB 10.4, I've got a trigger that calls sys_exec to run an external script and that works fine.

I want to add value looked up from a table other than the one the trigger is on and include that value in the sys_exec command. This is the trigger creation statement I've tried (I've tried lots of different ways but with no success).

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `table1_after_update` AFTER update ON `table1` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE myvar int(10) unsigned;
    select anotherfield into myvar from table2 where table2.id=NEW.id;
    SET @exec_var = sys_exec(CONCAT('test.sh ', NEW.id, ' ', myvar));

END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

if I add the trigger with only the sys_exec line and use only NEW.id instead of myvar then it works correctly and test.sh logs the value. No matter what I've tried, when I do an update on table1, I get an SQL error saying

> Error Code 1054: Unknown column 'anothervalue' in 'field list'

Despite this being an AFTER update trigger, it seems to be altering the SQL that is being executed against the database and I have no idea where I'm going wrong.

Comment: It is unclear to me, if anothervalue is a local variable, a field in table2 or a table, or a session variable. You have anothervalue in all 4 roles in three lines of the body of the trigger. Since we do not know anything about your data structure, it is really difficult for us to suggest a solution. Your select into statement does not make any sense at all.

Comment: apologies - I'm a long time mysql/mariadb user but I'm extremely new to triggers and variables. anothervalue is intended to be retrieved from the  anothertable.anothervalue column and then fed out into the sys_exec command. I suspect the DECLARE is a red herring - that was my flailing around trying to get it to work any way I could. My goal is to pull the associated "anothervalue" column from "anothertable" and add it to other columns from NEW. without having to do external lookups in a file system script

Comment: It seems that the select into may be reversed, and where clause use? ... I think you meant to do: `select stbid into anothervalue from table2 where table2.table1id=NEW.id;` ?

Comment: apoligies - that's my bad again. I've edited the question to try and be a little clearer now that I'm not posting tired after a frustrating day.  With the trigger above, mariadb will let me create the trigger but won't allow any updates to the table that the trigger is on.